# pyspark do calculation for each row against other rows and get max

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to do some calculations for each row against every other row in the table, and then keep the max one in a new column.

For example, I want to compute `(x / x * y)` for each row in the following dataframe:

```
id       score        
A        1.2        
B        4.5       
C        0.8      
D        1.1
E        6.7
```

A would do calculations with all other rows B, C, D, E

It is like doing a nested for loop:

```py
for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < table.length; j++)
    if(i == j) continue
    result = score-from-A / (score-from-A * score-from-B)
    if(result > max_score_A_current_has)
      max_score_A_current_has = result
```

Here is the expected output. The formula is `x / (x * y)`

```
id       score      max  
A        1.2        1.25 because max in 0.2 (A-B), 1.25 (A-C), 0.9 (A-D)
B        4.5        1.25                0.83 (B-A), 1.25 (B-C), 0.91 (B-D)
C        0.8        0.9                 0.83 (C-A), 0.2 (C-B), 0.9 (C-D)
D        1.1        1.25                0.83 (D-A), 0.2 (D-B), 1.25 (D-C)
```

I can't figure out how to do this in pyspark.

Comment: Add expected output and explain your question more in detail

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to compare each row with every other row (from what I understand), the only option is a Cartesian product. You could do it with the following code:

```py
# creating the input data
df = spark.createDataFrame(
          [('A', 1.2), ('B', 4.5), ('C', .8), ('D', 1.1), ('E', 6.7)],
          ['id', 'score']
)

# renaming columns for clarity
df2 = df.select(df['id'].alias('id2'), df['score'].alias('score2'))

# And using the crossJoin function (Cartesian product)
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df\
    .crossJoin(df2)\
    .where(F.col('id') != F.col('id2'))\
    .withColumn("result", F.col('score') / (F.col('score') * F.col('score2')))\
    .groupBy("id", "score")\
    .agg(F.max(F.col('result')).alias("max"))\
    .orderBy("id").show()
```

Which yields:

```
+---+-----+------------------+                                                  
| id|score|               max|
+---+-----+------------------+
|  A|  1.2|              1.25|
|  B|  4.5|              1.25|
|  C|  0.8|0.9090909090909091|
|  D|  1.1|              1.25|
|  E|  6.7|              1.25|
+---+-----+------------------+
```

**EDIT**
In case you want to know which id yielded the maximum result, you can use the `struct` function like this:

```py
df\
    .crossJoin(df2)\
    .where(F.col('id') != F.col('id2'))\
    .withColumn("result", F.col('score') / (F.col('score') * F.col('score2')))\
    .withColumn("s", F.struct(F.col('result'), F.col('id2')))\
    .groupBy("id", "score")\
    .agg(F.max(F.col('s')).alias('s'))\
    .select('id', 'score', F.col('s.result').alias('max'),
                 F.col('s.id2').alias('id2'))\
    .orderBy('id').show()
```

Comment: is there a way to show what is the id that produced the max score for each row?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with either a window or a struct containing both the score and the id so that they are aggregated together.

Comment: something like  T.StructType([T.StructField('id', T.StringType(), True), T.StructField('score', T.DoubleType(), True)] ? Can you also put it in your answer? Thanks!